# Can you temporarily remove AdMob ads from an iOS / Android app remotely?

Tags: admob

Is there a way to temporarily remove an AdMob ad from an iOS/Android app without having to release a new version?

For example, is there an option I can enable/disable on AdMob.com so the ad doesn't appear?

Answer (score 2):

No. The closest you can get is limiting the amount of ads that show per user on AdMob.com. Navigate to Monetize, select your application, and then its ad unit.

[image]

You could change the days to something larger, 30 for example, but the user will still see the initial ad and another ad once the amount of days has passed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I see that works for interstitials.  Cant seem to do anything equivalent for banners.  Do you know if there is a way?

Comment: @CharlieSeligman Oops sorry, didn't realize this wasn't an option for banner ad units. Ideally what you should do is update the app with an external flag that you control and can change on the fly if you ever want to disable/enabled ads in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Admob Meditation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation

2. Set 0% to each network that needs to be ignored.

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/06/distributing-ad-requests-for-admob.html

See network allocation Methods bullet 2

Percentages. Alternatively, you can assign percentage values to each ad network. Mediation randomly determines the first network using the given percentages, and then normalizes the remaining percentages to determine the next ad network. This process continues until all configured networks have been selected. **Note that any ad network with 0% percentage allocation will be ignored.**